# R Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L, : 8 arguments passed to .Internal(format) which requires 9

Tags: r

It has been a long time since the last time I used Rstudio.
Today I updated it to the latest and updated R to 3.2.2. After that I created a Rmd document and its default code just turned to be error.

```
summary(cars)
```

And here is the error

```
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
8 arguments passed to .Internal(format) which requires 9
```

It's not the only place that error happens.
I write this in my Rmd document.

```
plot(set1$x, set1$y, pch=19, cex=0.50, main="Points in Set #1")
```

Then the *same* error happened. But it's OK to code it in console directly.
Besides, some view() function also tragger the error.
It took me a long time and I can't find out what had happened.

---

I redownload R-3.2.0, and things fit well in there place. So my new question is what has been updated about function *format*.